# How to make Webpack run Mocha tests automatically?

Tags: webpack, mocha.js

I have Mocha and Babel installed, so in `package.json` I have:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.14.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "mocha": "^3.1.2",
    "mocha-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.4.1",
    "should": "^11.1.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.3"
}
```

And one simple test that starts with:

```
// import the libraries for testing ..
import Should from 'should';

describe("Bla-bla", function() { ... });
```

In my Webpack configuration I have the presets set already:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.(jsx|js)?$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            loader: "babel",
            query: {
                presets: ["es2015", "react"]
            }
        }
    ]
},
```

So:

1. How can I run the tests via webpack, so I automatically use babel?
2. If I try via `mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register testsfile.js` - I get:

   ```
   import Should from 'should';
   ^^^^^^
   SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
   ```

Aadding `.babelrc` file with `{ "presets": ["es2015"] }` inside makes the error go away, but I don't want to pollute my environment with dotfiles  files anymore, and also - I want to make the `mocha` tests run automatically upon file save.

PS: Also - I tried with another webpack server, with `npm` script like this:

```
webpack-dev-server 'mocha!./testfile.js' --output-filename test.js --port 8081
```

I wanted to have the result on different web page, but it only servers the application itself, and no test results.